# Cheapest way to ship three cubic meters from Oklahoma to Spain?

Tags: shipping

Related, but not sure they fit exactly:
[Transporting a large number of books from USA to UK](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/transporting-a-large-number-of-books-from-usa-to-uk) 
[Sending myself things from the US to Europe: how do import taxes work?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/sending-myself-things-from-the-us-to-europe-how-do-import-taxes-work)

I have maybe three cubic meters of stuff that I haven't yet had time to sort through, so I'd like to bring it with me rather than store it for however long I'm on the road.  (It is what's left of sixty years of accumulation by me and my late wife, both not-quite-hoarders but pretty close.)

I'm not changing permanent residence because I don't have one.  Sold it when I retired.

There are some books, some clothes, some electronic parts, more than ten photo albums, and **lots** of paper (files).  I'm guessing three cubic meters.  Certainly far less than ten.  Resale value less than a hundred US dollars.

Can I travel with it on a freighter without paying a fortune?  I noticed that some of the luxury cruises have luggage limits almost as stingy as airlines.

iContainers.com quotes US$ 350 and up (assuming 50 KG & 3 m³) but I'd have to come up with a big enough box myself.

Comment: [Uline](https://www.uline.com/Product/Detail/S-11302/Wood-Crates/Wood-Crate-41-x-28-3-4-x-25-1-2?pricode=WY871&gadtype=pla&id=S-11302&gclid=CNno_fPmztACFU46gQodOy4Hqg&gclsrc=aw.ds) for shipping crates

Comment: I had a full-size container with stuff shipped for around 1200$, but that was a decade ago. Just remember to consider that freight is not air-conditioned (unless you pay for it). It can get rather hot in a container on top of a ship in the sun, your photo albums might melt together (mine did).

Comment: Were the photos themselves salvageable?  I want to get rid of them all, but I'd like to scan them first.

Comment: You might want to redo your estimates.  3 cubic meters of paper would weigh more like 2000 kg than 50.

Comment: LOTS of paper, not ALL paper!  When I retired it was five boxes with the heaviest thirty kilograms but now it's two boxes not quite full.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about price-shopping for a specific service.